# Hide the skipped pipeline in gitlab UI with gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

As you can see in [this gitlab.com issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28369) , with simple commit in current branch, you must skip the second pipeline automatically triggered, with `-o ci.skip` like this

```
build-job:
 stage: build
 rules:
  - when: always
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
 script:
  - echo "GIT job started."
  - git config user.name "${CUSTOM_NAME}"
  - git config user.email "${CUSTOM_EMAIL}"
  - git config pull.rebase true
  - git remote set-url origin https://oauth2:${GITLAB_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git
  - git checkout -b main
  - git push -u -f origin main
  - ls -liaF
  - echo "new content" | tee README.md
  - git add .
  - git commit -m "list updated."
  - git push origin HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -o ci.skip
  - echo "GIT job passed."
```

The workaround with $DO_CI seems not working anymore, do you have any tips for hide from UI this skipped pipeline ? You can see [here](https://gitlab.com/fredericpetit/overdeploy-datas-example/-/commits/main) how skipped pipelines appears.

Comment: the variable workaround should work if used in `workflow:rules:` with the appropriate [push option](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html) to set the variable. Alternatively, you can try setting a `workflow:rules:` based on `$CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR` assuming you use a specific author for automated commits.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is directly supported by GitLab.

As a workaround, you might consider defining rules in jobs that check the commit message and determine whether to execute them. If the commit message contains the phrase "`[ci skip]`", the job will only be executed manually and is allowed to fail.
For instance:

```yaml
rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /skip ci/'
    when: manual
    allow_failure: true
```

This will cause the job to only be run when manually executed if the commit message contains "`skip ci`".

[This thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-skip-the-pipeline-from-job-gitlab/44947)
mentions that you can always run the whole pipeline from a branch, and it will skip the mark. This might be another workaround to consider.